# Setup cmd.exe parameter when starting ConEmu

Tags: conemu

I have some configuration setting in **config.bat**, I can manually execute it using `cmd.exe /k "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\config.bat"`

How can I setup ConEmu to execute cmd.exe with parameters ?

I tried to put the **cmd.exe + parameters** in the **Task parameters..** and **Commands (application, argument)..**, but neither of them is working.

Please help, thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not related to ConEmu at all. Moreover it's not clear what is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed it just by a inch :-)

Simply put the `cmd /k &lt;path>\&lt;to>\&lt;your>\config.bat` in the Commands text area.

(sorry I can not post images yet)